# Is there a jQuery gallery/slideshow plugin that matches these criteria?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, gallery, slideshow

Can anyone point me in the direction of a jQuery slideshow/gallery plugin that matches these criteria (or can be customized to through setting its options)?

- Can be inserted into a div - not a popup display
- No border/thumbnails/filenames/buttons - when an element is being displayed, that's all you can see
- I need to able able to set a max height and width for the gallery as a percentage of the page dimensions. If an image is being displayed, it needs to be re-sized to fit this whilst maintaining its aspect ratio.
- Can display any type of element (although if it can only display images I'm still interested)

I've had a look at some plugins, but I can't find one that is suitable. Is there one? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Thickbox or lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

You want to display it in a popup or not?

You can try Cycle plugin - I've used it many times and it's stable. For resizing the images according to the page's dimensions, you can do that before applying the plugin, either with PHP or jQuery.